# How to control multiple CoundownTimer in android

Tags: android, timer

Currently in my app i have the user create multiple countdown timer whenever they click a button. I wish to pair every countdown timer to a cancel button which allows the user to cancel the countdown timer. Currently I have a function which cancels the countdown timer using cdt.cancel() where cdt is the countdowntimer var. However that only allows me to cancel the cdt that was previously created. Is there any way i can cancel for example the countdown timer before that?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: store other timer in other variable, or even a List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
   private void startNewTimer(List<CountDownTimer> listOfTimers) {


        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();

        listOfTimers.add(countDownTimer);

    }

    private boolean cancelTimers(List<CountDownTimer> listOfTimers) {

        if(listOfTimers != null && !listOfTimers.isEmpty()) {
            for(CountDownTimer cdt : listOfTimers) {
                cdt.cancel();
            }
            listOfTimers = null;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

You may want to create your `List<CountDownTimer> listOfTimers` as a global variable (`List<CountDownTimer> listOfTimers = new ArrayList<>()`)

You would call the the `startNewTimer(list)` from the `onClick` method of your button `OnClickListener` and the `stopTimers` where you see fit.

If you want to cancel a specific cancel you could reference it through its index in the `List` likes this:

```
private boolean stopTimer(List<CountDownTimer> listOfTimers, int index) {

        if(listOfTimers != null && listOfTimers.size() > index) {
            for(int i = 0; i < listOfTimers.size(); i++) {
                listOfTimers.get(i).cancel();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```